# How to fix (sporadically) jerky animation for loading books or using enchanting/alchemy/smithing instruments in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been experiencing some very weird, jerky motion when loading books or as my character uses an Alchemy table, Arcane Enchanter, or tanning rack. I'm pretty sure this has happened with the other Smithing "tools" as well, but I've been unable to confirm it at the moment. It doesn't always happen, and the degree of jerkiness varies. I've been assuming this was due to overheating and have taken to cooling my computer more, but that doesn't seem to be it. Has anyone else experienced this glitch? If so, is there a good fix?

Here are my system specs (Thanks for reminding me David Starkey!) ->

1. Intel Core i5 2.40 GHz Dual Core.
2. 4GB RAM, 3.87 usable.
3. ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series Graphics card.
4. Windows 7 64 Bit.

Graphics Settings for Skyrim: Medium Graphics (No Anisotropic filtering, No Antialiasing, Advanced options not modified) at 1280 x 720 Resolution.

Edits to SkryimPrefs.ini (All other sections are auto-generated) ->

> ```
> [Launcher]
> bEnableFileSelection=1
> bShowAllResolutions=0
> uLastAspectRatio=3
> bLoadLooseFiles=1
> ```

That's the only section I changed. The change was for the launcher to stop graying out the "Data Files" option. I think the load loose files was set before my edit. I've got the Dawngaurd dlc, but I'm not loading it. I've got no mods.

NOTE: My laptop heats up quite a bit after a few hours of play. I use a cooling pad, and when I check to see if it is too hot. When it is, I put the laptop on an ice-pack and continue, or quit the game for a while. Sometimes I quit and leave it on the ice-pack. It certainly don't think that it was extremely hot, but I don't have much of a standard to judge by here.

Hopefully this will help clarify the situation and find the fix.

Comment: Could it be your hardware?  What graphics card do you have?

Comment: @David Starkey I've added a bunch of information that might help. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: My first thought is that this is heat related.  Most of my "glitchy graphics" issues can be attributed to this.  You might want to take the laptop apart and blow out any dust, hair, or other gunk.  See if that either fixes the issue, or allows you to play for longer.

Comment: Is V-sync on or off?

Comment: @galacticninja I did not turn it off, so I suppose it is on! I'll double check by finding the way to turn it off and post.

Comment: It could also be that the graphics settings for the game are turned up too high for your RAM or GPU to handle. I have 8GB of RAM (played this game on 4GB originally) and an Intel HD3000 series GPU in my laptop and I have most of my settings turned down to minimum. Never experienced the issues you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to clean it. That happens to me when to much dust builds up in system or in air vents.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I do believe I cleaned my computer at the time of posting, but I don't recall exactly. I will try to reproduce it again and see what happens with a clean computer.